# Cannot handle numeric class! inspite of there being no numeric class in data

Tags: java, weka, naivebayes

This is my data.

```
@Relation tagging

@ATTRIBUTE word STRING
@ATTRIBUTE postag STRING
@ATTRIBUTE ctag STRING
@ATTRIBUTE class STRING

@DATA
routing, NN, I-NP, P
is, VBZ, B-VP, N
a, DT, B-NP, N
crucial, JJ, I-NP, N
product, NN, I-NP, N
., ., O, N
```

and yet I get an error saying

> weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException:
>   weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial: Cannot handle numeric
>   class!

when I try to build a classifier

Which numeric class is it talking about?

Comment: Maybe it just takes `-` as minus? Or `.` as 0.0?

Comment: But it's been assigned the String data type!

Answer (score 0):

Before classifying, apply the Unsupervised Attribute Filter "StringToNominal"  on the last attribute.

By the way, maybe "class" is not such a good attribute name.

Comment: If I make the last attribute nominal in the data itself, will that help? Or does it have to be done using the filter?

Comment: Can you please provide a source code example?

Answer (score 0):

I used the StringToWordVector Filter to solve this problem,

```
StringToWordVector stwv = new StringToWordVector();
stwv.setInputFormat(data);
try {
    fsource = Filter.useFilter(data, stwv);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

applying it to the Instances (data) after I had specified which attribute would be class using

```
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
```

(And I changed the name of the last attribute)
Thanks, @knb that was good advice.